# How do I return an InternalErrorResult?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I am using Swagger with a .Net Core API.
When there is a bug in the API I want to receive an InternalServerError
However there is no NotOK method to do this.

Currently I have the following in my base controller

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult RouteInterfaceMethod<TResponse>(Func<TResponse> function)
        {
        //    try
        //    {
                IActionResult res = null;
                TResponse ret = function();
                res = Ok(ret);
                return res;
        //    }
        //    catch (Exception e)
        //    {
        //       var msg = MakeErrorMessage(e);
        //       return base.NotFound( msg);
        //    }
        }
    }
}
```

And am about to  un-comment the code ,is there an alternative to using NotFound()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return InternalServerError in this way

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   var msg = MakeErrorMessage(e);
   return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, msg);
}
```

or just re-throw an exception

```
 catch (Exception e)
 {
       var msg = MakeErrorMessage(e);
       throw;
 }
```

Comment: I asked a related question ~https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402878/error-in-autorest-generated-api-consumer-microsoft-rest-httpoperationexception~